# Is a signing bonus considered reportable income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income, employment, form-1099-misc

I received a $2,000 bonus for signing a Letter of Intent to sign a contract leasing our farm land to a solar energy developer. The lease ultimately fell through due to technical complications, but I did receive the $2,000 bonus. However, I have not received a 1099 form for this payment. My question is, must I still report this money on my tax return and if so, how?

Also, we had $1200 I attorney's fees for negotiating the contract that ultimately fell through. Are these legal fees deductible as an expense, and where would I list them?

Comment: Is your farm a working business with revenue and expenses?

Answer (score 2):

> I received a $2,000 bonus...

[Gross Income](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rr-07-19.pdf) is income from whatever source derived, including (but not limited to) “compensation for services, including fees, commissions, fringe benefits, and similar items.” 
 [Adjusted Gross Income](https://www.irs.gov/uac/definition-of-adjusted-gross-income) is defined as gross income minus adjustments to income.

> My question is, must I still report this money on my tax return and if so, how?

Yes, and it would be on line 21 of your 1040 with supporting documentation.

> Are these legal fees deductible as an expense, and where would I list them?

[Yes](http://taxation.lawyers.com/tax-audits/are-attorneys-fees-tax-deductible.html), you would aggregate your deductible expenses and place these on your [Schedule A](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sa.pdf). Instructions [here](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sca.pdf).

Good Luck.

**Edit:** As Ben Miller pointed out in the comments, the deduction would be placed in either line 23 or 28 depending on the nature of the attorney (investment related or not).

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. Where exactly do you think he should deduct the legal fees on the schedule A?

Comment: Stated is the linked yes, "Generally, you deduct personal attorney fees as an itemized miscellaneous deduction on Schedule A of your Form 1040 tax return." Depending on the nature (investment or not) it would be either lines 23 or 28.

Comment: I was thinking that this would be business income/expense, going on a schedule C and allowing you to deduct the entire expense. What do you think?

Comment: On line 17 of the Schedule C? No, because this is a farm he would have to file a Schedule F, specifically line 32a. "You can include on this line fees charged by accountants and attorneys that are ordinary and necessary expenses directly related to your farming business." - Instructions from Schedule F. But this does raise a question between if this bonus is GI on the 1040, or should be reported on a Form 8919...